# Get the list of Projects under selected solution in TFS Build definition

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild

Is there any way by which i can get the number of projects under selected solution in my build definition.

I am creating a parameter of type Drop down List, which should be got filed by the number of projects (.csproj) the solution has.

I have to do this calculation before queuing the build, so that i can ask the user to select any of projects from list to deploy.

Can anybody tell me how can i do this in TFS Build template.

Comment: If you are trying to make dynamic drop down list based on number of solutions to build I think i will have to disappoint you. Dynamic drop down list really easy to make, but i don't think there is a way to dynamically access solutions to build from other definition part. you can do it during the build easily. I made drop down list load data from xml. The only think that comes to my mind is popup that you select projects from list, but also there is text box to add more solutions manually. If thats something you want to do I can help you get started.

Comment: During the build you can do it easily, but you can't do it in build definition that reflects real time values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can calculate the number of projects under a selected solution in Build Definition. Metadata about a process parameter contains a piece of information **Editor**, this is a string that specifies a custom editor for the parameter, there is not a method to calculate the number of projects under a selected solution in Build Definition. See the [Editor Attribute help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) for more information on the syntax.